# Use same function on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need this function to work on multiple elements in the form, right now it only works on `TfDiagnosis`.
How do I use it on `TfDiagnosis` and `TfDiagnosis2` with results in `TfSnowmed` and `TfSnowmed2`?

**JQUERY**

```
$(function snowmedlist() {
    $('#TfDiagnosis').on('click keyup change blur', function() {  
        if ($('#TfDiagnosis').val() == '[D]Anterograde amnesia (780.93)') {
            $('#TfSnowmed').val(206789002);
        }
        if ($('#TfDiagnosis').val() == '[D]Chills with fever (780.60)') {
            $('#TfSnowmed').val(206760004);
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input name="TfDiagnosis" type="text" id="TfDiagnosis" size="100">
<input type="text" name="TfSnowmed" id="TfSnowmed">
<input name="TfDiagnosis2" type="text" id="TfDiagnosis2" size="100" >
<input type="text" name="TfSnowmed2" id="TfSnowmed2"></td>
```

Comment: You should use classes here, not Ids

Comment: Thanks. How would that affect the coding though? TfDiagnosis could have a different value than TfDiagnosis2 and as a result TfSnowmed and TfSnowmed2 should also have different matched values.

Comment: Maybe then you should improve your question. Hard for me to figure out  what you are expecting here

Comment: Quoting from your comment: "My actual if/else list has over 400 values." Well then you should rethink all your logic, that's not how coding usually works

Comment: I agree, that's why I am seeking assistance. My employer has asked that I add additional fields with the same functionality.

Comment: Look @Diodeus answer, it would be really really better approach, even i'd use an object, not an array but... BTW, data should be retrieved from database, not hard coded. Maybe it is already your case, don't know. And if you generate HTML dynamically server side, you could just set custom data-* attributes

Comment: ...just set custom data-* attributes **for each specific element**

Comment: I'll try to be more precise in what I am trying to accomplish. This form is for patient diagnosis. The doctor may enter more than one diagnosis, actually they want up to 5 text boxes where they can be entered. I need to match the diagnosis entered to a code, for each of the diagnoses entered. I wanted to use an array because we cant query the server for the data, but I didn't want build a function for each of the 5 possible data enter points.

Comment: You could still post on code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to work on  groups of elements using class names.

```
<input name="TfDiagnosis" type="text" id="TfDiagnosis" class="diagnosis" size="100">
<input type="text" name="TfSnowmed" id="TfSnowmed">
```

js:

```
$('.diagnosis').on('click keyup change blur', function() {
    if($(this).val() == "...") {
        $(this).next().val(1.00);
    }
})
```

This way `.next()` is always the next element, so you don't need to keep passing IDs around. You can then store the data outside of the function to get rid of a cluster of IF statements:

```
var myData = []
myData['[D]Anterograde amnesia (780.93)'] = '206789002';
myData['[D]Chills with fever (780.60)'] = '206760004';
```

...then substitute the look-up from the array....

```
$('.diagnosis').on('click keyup change blur', function() {
        $(this).next().val(myData[$(this).attr(id)]);
})
```

Comment: Giving this a try. :)

Comment: Try setting it up on jsfiddle.net and sharing the link here.

Comment: I'll try to be more precise in what I am trying to accomplish. This form is for patient diagnosis. The doctor may enter more than one diagnosis, actually they want up to 5 text boxes where they can be entered. I need to match the diagnosis entered to a code, for each of the diagnoses entered. I wanted to use an array because we cant query the server for the data, but I didn't want build a function for each of the 5 possible data enter points.

Comment: You're probably better off using an auto-completer that looks up values from a database - this database can be loaded as a JS file, much like the array I describe. The person would type and they then select one of the matches sine there could be a huge number of choices.

Comment: I was finally able to get this to work, to a little effort but you can see it here: [linl](http://jsfiddle.net/YrSDf/6/). Thanks so much Diodeus2!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$('#TfDiagnosis, #TfDiagnosis2').on('click keyup change blur', function() {  
     if($(this).attr('id') == 'TfDiagnosis' ){
           if ($(this).val() == '[D]Anterograde amnesia (780.93)') {
              $('#TfSnowmed').val(206789002);
           }
           if ($(this).val() == '[D]Chills with fever (780.60)') {
              $('#TfSnowmed').val(206760004);
           } 
       }else{
           //Stuff to do in case it is the #TfDiagnosis2
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to make your function work on multiple inputs is to use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click keyup change blur', 'input', function() {
    var value = $(this).val(); //Get the value only once 

    if (value == '[D]Anterograde amnesia (780.93)') {
        $('#TfSnowmed').val(206789002);
    }
    else if (value == '[D]Chills with fever (780.60)') {
        $('#TfSnowmed').val(206760004);
    }
});
```

Which will call the function for *any* input on the page. You probably want to assign a class to the specific inputs you want to use like so:

**HTML**

```
<input name="TfDiagnosis" type="text" id="TfDiagnosis" class="TfInput" size="100">
<input type="text" name="TfSnowmed" id="TfSnowmed" class="TfInput">
<input name="TfDiagnosis2" type="text" id="TfDiagnosis2" class="TfInput" size="100" >
<input type="text" name="TfSnowmed2" id="TfSnowmed2" class="TfInput">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on('click keyup change blur', '.TfInput', function() {
    var value = $(this).val(); //Get the value only once 

    if (value == '[D]Anterograde amnesia (780.93)') {
        $('#TfSnowmed').val(206789002);
    }
    else if (value == '[D]Chills with fever (780.60)') {
        $('#TfSnowmed').val(206760004);
    }
});
```